# Mysql export with Auto_Increment=1

Tags: mysql, export, auto-increment

Is there a way for Mysql workbench (or anyother tool) to export a Database Schema without it's data, and not automatically setting the `AutoIncrement` value to table row count?

ex : I use the `--no-data option` on MySql Workbench Export. Lets say there was actualy 100 rows of data on the table before export, then exported script will have no data, but `AUTO_INCREMENT=100` on table creation script.

I need to be able to create an empty DB creation script on the fly for backup and deployment purposes.

Comment: If it's for backup, wouldn't it be important that the data is also in there? :)

Comment: I only need to be able to generate a deployment script for development and 'deployment' purposes for an application. For every change in the database I create a deployment script, and I do this quite often. Each time I need to go back and set AUTO_INCREMENT=1 on all tables :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, always there is way. 
While exporting structure only in the mysql, one checkbox need to be unchecked i.e "AUTO_INCREMENT" under the Object creation options options (just above the go button) and the result you will get as expected.

Please let me know, if you have any query.

Comment: How are you exporting the structure and where is the check-box? Thank you.

Comment: That checkbox doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem, but I`ve made solution:

```
mysqldump --no-data=true -u username -p dbname > table.sql && sed -i 's/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]\+/AUTO_INCREMENT=1/g' table.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and finally found the solution.
The problem is that when you imported your data, it stored the current autoincrement value of the table into the model.
As you want it to 1, you need to manually edit this value before exporting the model as SQL.

For this :

1. Right click on the table name and choose `Edit '<Table name>'` (or double click on it)
2. Under `Options` tab and `General Options`, change the `Auto Increment` value to 1
3. Save your model
4. Export it

[image]